# Sorting by nested object in GraphQL + Relay

Tags: sorting, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I have the following trivial structure.

Table **Tasks** with foreign key **teamId**. And **Teams** table with a **name** column.

I have a Relay compliant GraphQL and if I wanted to get the Tasks with the Teams I would do something like that.

```
{
  taskNodes {
    Tasks: nodes {
      id,
      description
      Team: teamByTeamId {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if I wanted to sort by the task description

```
{
  taskNodes(orderBy: DESCRIPTION) {
    Tasks: nodes {
      id,
      description
      Team: teamByTeamId {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to sort by the Team name column. How how could you do that in GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `taskNodes` field takes an `orderBy` argument in the form of an Enum. GraphQL doesn't have generic sort functionality--it's all done through arguments passed into the fields.

When you use GraphiQL, the interactive query explorer for GraphQL, it should tell you what the available options for `orderBy` are. If there isn't anything that looks like `TEAM_NAME` or similar, you'll need to ask your API developer to add a new option.